# Fragment error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Estoy trabajando con fragments, e hice un nuevo fragment en el que necesito usar un botón que encienda la linterna del móvil. El problema es que al intentar declararlo me da error, (igual me da error en el @Override):

```
package com.example.oscarsierra.bladenotes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


public class LinternaFragment extends Fragment {
Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void OnClick(View v){

        }
    });
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_linterna, container, false);
}
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder asociar los objetos a los que has creado en la vista, en los fragment es un poco diferente.

Lo tienes que hacer en el método onCreateView, no en el método onCreate.

Para poder llamar al método findViewById lo tienes que hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nombreTab, container, false);
```

Donde container es un atributo del método, como puedes ver en tu código.
Después, ya puedes asociarlo a partir del objeto view:

```
button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Comment: Lo hice como me indicaste y funcionó, (le añadí un `return view` porque me lo pidió, ahora el fragment sí abre pero al querer presionar el botón para encender la linterna, ¡La aplicación se detiene! ¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Si, perfecto, tienes que devolver esa view que creas. Ahora habría que ver que error te da al intentar encender la linterna. Pon un try catch y mira que excepción te da y dónde